# Best practice for screen/page tracking across Web and Mobile app using Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, firebase-analytics, gtag.js

My product consists of a website, an iOS app, and an Android app. All of them are having the same set of screens.

I try to set up them so that I can see combined analytics data (e.g. average engagement time on each screen, screen view, interesting app event) in Google Analytics. I wonder what is the best practice to achieve that.

I set up a GA4 property with 3 data streams for Android app, iOS app, and website. I let Android app and iOS app manually send `screen_view` event with the same screen name. This way it is possible to see analytics data like avg. engagement time from Android/iOS combined.

But for website, `gtag.js` uses `page_view` and it logs 3 informations: `page_title` (default=document.title), `page_location` (default=location.href), and `page_path` (default=location.pathname).

In GA dashboard > Engagement > Screen and Page, they provided data filters of 4 possibilities:

1. Page title and screen class
2. Page path and screen class
3. Page title and screen name
4. Content group

It seems I have the following choices:

1. Let my website to manually send `page_view` with `page_title=screen name` that app is using. Then I can see combined engagement data using **Page title and screen name** option.
2. Let my app (iOS and Android) to send screen class as page path. Then use **Page path and screen class**.

The 1st choices is more feasible for me, but still require a lot of effort. Is there any other solution to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to come up with own event - it requires a lot of effort. Such as event name `page [name: <anything from app/website>]`.

Anyway from my experience I recommend to use built-in events page_view, screen_view for better manipulation across GA4, BigQuery, DataStudio. GA4 interface is built for such events.

For naming screens I recommend to create (at least) google sheet documentation with 3 columns (at least) - Web, Android, iOS. At the end you will end up with amazing GA4 capabilities. Think about Pareto principle 80/20, it is not required to log all of the interactions.